# writeFile output issues. Didn't show what I expected to see

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand how can I write the file like this:

```json
{
    "726623241984278589": {
        "322366672625467392": {
            "Moderation": "Kick",
            "Target": "Bobo#1601",
            "Moderator": "Bobosky#3914",
            "Reason": "Testing",
            "ID": "#XLR6RV8M"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the my code of fs.writeFile:

```js
const TargetMemberID = TargetMember.id

data[message.guild.id] = {
    TargetMemberID: {
        Moderation: 'Kick',
        Target: `${TargetMember.user.tag}`,
        Moderator: `${message.author.tag}`,
        Reason: `${Reason}`,
        ID: `#${ID}`
    }
}

fs.writeFile("./data.json", JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

but it out put like this:

```json
{
    "726623241984278589": {
        "TargetMemberID": {
            "Moderation": "Kick",
            "Target": "Bobo#1601",
            "Moderator": "Bobosky#3914",
            "Reason": "Testing",
            "ID": "#XLR6RV8M"
        }
    }
}
```

so this is not what I expected to see. I want to see the TargetMemberID above replaced by the number just like what I expected as the first json code.
Any clue on it?

I've tried making the writing part as

```js
data[message.guild.id[TargetMember.id]]
```

but it doesn't work.

PS : I didn't put all my codes such as the definding part of TargetMember, Reason etc. All of those are based on discord.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, object keys are strings, so when you write `TargetMemberID` as key, it's the same as writing `"TargetMemberID"`. If you want the key to be the value of `TargetMemberID`, you need to add square brackets around it. And this way you could also just use `TargetMember.id`, you don't need a new variable for this.

Also, you don't need to use template literals in those values, you can just pass them as below.

```js
data[message.guild.id] = {
    [TargetMember.id]: {
        Moderation: 'Kick',
        Target: TargetMember.user.tag,
        Moderator: message.author.tag,
        Reason: Reason,
        ID: ID,
    }
}
```

You could also use the shorthand syntax, when the object key and the variable is the same:

```js
data[message.guild.id] = {
    [TargetMember.id]: {
        Moderation: 'Kick',
        Target: TargetMember.user.tag,
        Moderator: message.author.tag,
        // same as Reason: Reason
        Reason,
        // same as ID: ID
        ID,
    }
}
```